# Dynamically call a function in a given module

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, modules

I use the following code that is working **as expected** and I want to get some feedback from the community how I can Improve it...

> The code does the following:

1. Get Some request with specific action to run which is describe in JSON file
   e.g. URL is like aaa/bbb/invokeFn
2. Find this invokeFn in the config.json and call to function with the same name in the module
   the files are located in folder under the project.

Please refer to my JavaScript and I need help with the followings

> 1. Does it make sense to divide it for two functions or maybe more?
> 2. How you put the variables better? Between those two function.
> 3. Any other feedback how can I **improve the code in JS** will be very helpfull

```js
 run: function (req, res, urlPath) {

                var pluginPath = constants.INT;
                var extPluginPath = constants.EXT;

                var isFnCalled = false;
                globby([objPath,extobjPath ])
                    .then(function (extensions) {
                        extensions.forEach(function (file) {
                            if (!isFnCalled) {

                                var filePath = file.split('/');
                                var fileName = filePath[filePath.length - 1];
                                var reqFile = "../" + filePath[2] + "/" + fileName;

                                isFnCalled = runFunction( req,res,reqFile,isFnCalled, urlPath);
                            }
                        });
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.log('error: ', err);
                    }
                )
            }
        };

        var runFunction = function (req, res,reqFile, isFnCalled, urlPath) {
            var rAction = urlPath[2];
            //require JSON
            var config = require(reqFile + 'on');
            //require Module
            var obj = require(reqFile);
            for (var provider in config.providers[0]) {
                if ((config.providers[0][provider].path === rAction && !isFnCalled)
                    && (req.method === config.providers[0][provider].method.toUpperCase())) {
                    var fnName = config.providers[0][provider].function;
                    if (typeof obj[config.providers[0][provider].function] === "function") {
                        try {
                            isFnCalled = true;
                            //invoke function
                            console.log("Function " + fnName + " is called");
                            obj[fnName](req, res, urlPath);
                        }
                        catch (err) {
                            res.status(500).send("Error returned from obj " + err);
                        }
                        if (!res.headerSent) {
                            res.end("function " + fnName + " finish successfully ", 200);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return isFnCalled;
        };
```

Comment: What are you doing with `isFnCalled` in main function?

Comment: @Neel - in case that that the function called( which pass the if condition for invoke function) I put the flag to true and exit the forEach loop...